# How to start chrome in headful (not headless) mode while connecting to the windows server with paramiko?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, paramiko

To give a background, I have 20 VPSs with Windows Server 2016 as OS and I am trying to run the same python script that uses selenium. So, for doing this, I use `paramiko` to ssh into all servers (I have installed openSSH to all of them and connection works, no problem there), and run the python command like this:

```
from paramiko import SSHClient, AutoAddPolicy


client = SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())
client.load_system_host_keys()

client.connect(host=host, username=username, password=password)


stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('python script-selenium.py')
```

If I change the code in **script-selenium.py** to use headless mode, everything works perfectly with no problems. But I want to use headful mode to visually verify the work of the script, but it doesn't spawn a window even though the script runs (I checked `stdout` and Task Manager in Server). So, my question is how I can make the chrome windows visible while running script with paramiko?

Comment: Please, provide the script-selenium.py code to understand the problem and tell us is GUI enabled (Desktop Experience) on your windows servers?

Comment: @BauyrzhanOspan, `script-selenium.py` is a basic code that creates a chrome browser, the problem is not with it as I am able to use Remote Desktop Connection to connect to server and run the script.

Answer (score 0):

try running a different command, like open notepad or command prompt or chrome itself via paramiko. that way we can check if its the permissions paramiko has when spawning a process.

```
from paramiko import SSHClient, AutoAddPolicy
client = SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())
client.load_system_host_keys()

client.connect(host=host, username=username, password=password)


stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('notepad.exe')
```

something like that ^

also try running the script on the machine via remote desktop to make sure it actually runs.

Comment: script works, I have verified it. but with paramiko it is not able to spawn headful chrome

Comment: it seems that you might be missing the driver for chrome. chrome driver link here (https://chromedriver.chromium.org/) add it to your python script path. maybe your python script isnt finding the driver and doesnt run.

Comment: thanks for the comment, but you haven't understood my question